# Making x macro work with do while 0

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, x-macros

I am trying to make x macro work with do while 0 as [checkpatch.pl](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/checkpatch.pl) is unhappy about it. However, it breaks the logic. Wondering if anyone have any suggestions to make it work?

```
#define X_TYPES do { \
        X(BABA, "baba") \
        X(INVALID, "invalid") \
} while (0)

#define X(type, name) type,
enum x_type {
    X_TYPES
};
#undef X                                                       
#define X(type, name) name,                                   
const char *x_name[] = {
    X_TYPES
};
#undef X    

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Olaf is the c preproc fundamental/independent enough to merit the removal of a generic c tag? Is this common practice in these tags?

Comment: Any reason you have a `main` in a device driver? How about reading the documentation how to write a driver? And why do you volontarily go to  macro hell for two simple entries?

Comment: @AndrasDeak: It definitively is not common practice to tag for two unrelated languages at once. Whether using the C tag is disputable, as given, it seems OP is asking about the macros. Alltogether the question si very unclear and the code looks like something copypasta'd together without knowing what how that works.

Comment: Sidenote: that's not how X-macros work. Before hacking code together, learn the language and understand the concepts you intend to use. (not that using x-macros here is a good idea).

Comment: @Olaf: Not only the preprocessing-stage seems of interest to the OP, but also that the reslt is valid C doing what he wants.

Comment: @Olaf I'm aware that tagging with both c and c++ is bad form. What I'm asking is whether either should've been kept along with the preproc one. The usual reason is that c and c++ are different languages. Along these lines this is loosely as if somebody tagged something with python, java and nullpointerexception, and you'd only leave the last one with no language tag. So is [tag:c-preprocessor] a standalone language? Do the majority of the people who are experts follow it? Edit: you've tagged it now with c so this is moot anyway ;)

Comment: What do while is supposed to do?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I re-added the C tag even before your comment. Nevertheless this does not generate valid C code. Statements are not alloed in a _enum-specifier_. The code shows massive missconception about how x-macros actually work.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: _sigh_ I initially removed both, C and C++ tags because from title it seemed to be a cpp-only quetion. Nevertheless, it seems OP just did not understand the idea of x-macros. If I had votes left, I'd CVed as "unclear". FYI: The cpp can be used stand-alone. It just happens to be included in ther C language spec, but e.g. the C++ spec refrences this part of the C standard. Also cpp is used for non-C code. E.g. you could very well preprocess Java code. See the `cpp` command on your platform: it invokes the C preprocessor only.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot wrap the X macro with `do while(0)`, because it will not be syntactically correct for the enumeration use cases that it is intended for.

Seek an exception mechanism in your checker script, or place the X macro into a separate source file that is excluded from being checked.